# Picker with image .net maui

Tags: android, xaml, maui, picker

I should create a picker with which I can select one of the texts supported by the relative images. I’ve only found examples of pickers that allow the selection of simple texts, I can’t find a solution. Is it possible?. I attach the mockup so you can get a better idea of what I mean.

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS1fn.png)

i used this code, can you adapt it?

```
<Picker x:Name="picker" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Title="Cosenza"
                    TitleColor="White"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="25"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Cosenza</x:String>
                        <x:String>Castrolibero</x:String>
                        <x:String>Mendicino</x:String>
                        <x:String>San Pietro in Guarano</x:String>
                        <x:String>San Vincenzo la Costa</x:String>
                        <x:String>Rende</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
```

Comment: Picker does not support templates.  You would need to build your own control using a ListView or CollectionView

Comment: @Jason thanks for the tip! Can you please give me an example code?

Comment: Please read the officials docs and samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be achieved using ListView or CollectionView. I made an example for you.

In xaml define a listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <HorizontalStackLayout >
                    <Label 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Image  
                           Source="{Binding ImageSource}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="30" 
                           WidthRequest="30" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In ViewModel, define an ObservableCollection called ItemCollectionObservableCollection which listview itemsource property bound to.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        CreateCollection();
    }

    private void CreateCollection()
    {
        ItemCollection.Add(
            new Item
            {
                Name = "Flower",
                ImageSource = "flower.png"
            });
        ItemCollection.Add(
            new Item
            {
                Name = "Star",
                ImageSource = "star.png"
            });
    }
}
```

Also create a new model class file:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
    }
}
```

That's an easy way using MVVM structure to create a ListView. And you UI is much more complicated. Only use ListView may not solve all questions. If you still have any question, feel free to ask.

For more info, you could refer to [.NET Maui ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: How do you make use of this ListView in a Picker? I get the full list on screen at all time instead of just when I want to select an item from the list as with a Picker

Comment: of course it's not a picker. Picker does not support template thus cannot put images in it. A listview or collectionview can be an alternative. You could add OnItemSelected event handler in respond to item selection. You could put listview in a popup page maybe. I just try to make listview act more like a picker.